# ADC outputs random values to constant input

Tags: adc, noise, sampling

I am using ADC ([ADS7822](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sbas062c/sbas062c.pdf)) from TI and I have some strange behaviour with it. Below diagram explains the voltage inputs and connections.

[image]

I was reading strange values with this setup.

1. I removed signal and provided a fixed DC voltage of 2V to PIN 2 (+In). I assume I will get some value for wich the MSB will be almost close to each other on each samples. I am comparing 400 samples at a time. But I receive dynamic outputs from the ADC wich has all possible values.
2. The first sample is always zero (surprising). I always get sampled values for 2V from the 2nd sample onwards.
3. Even if I don't provide and signal to PIN 2 (floating) it still outputs some data. I am providing clock and ss low so I assume it will sample noise if no signal is present. But the output should be close to each other. I receive all values from FFF to 000. I don't see such source of noise in my system.

Can someone suggest any possible reason for this behaviour?

Comment: How are you bypassing VREF and VCC? What voltage reference (part number) are you using to drive the VREF input? Any noise on VREF will directly affect the code measurement.

Comment: FYI: ADS7822 datasheet Layout section recommends 0.1uF ceramic on both VCC and VREF, and additionaly 1uF-10uF bypass on VCC.

Comment: @MarkU I am using REF3230, it is supposed to output 3.0V and I am getting 2.98 - 2.99V with multimeter. I have used a 10u close to the REF and a 0.1u close to ADC with the output of REF3230 (parallel).

Comment: To the Vcc of ADC I have used a 0.1u ceramic

Comment: Can you use an oscilloscope to capture scope shot of DCLOCK, DOUT, and CS waveforms? And if your oscilloscope has a "persist" display setting, this is a good time to use it -- capturing many overlapped CS cycles, and see whether the MSB really is toggling. There can be some LSB's variation but the MSB's should be stable. With +IN connected to VREF or VCC, the digital output should always be full-scale FFF.

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to give you an answer, because there is no obvious error. As my ideas exceed the limit of the comments, I write it as answer.

- Did you design the circuits around the ADC well? I.e. decoupling caps between Vcc and GND and Vref and GND, may be between In+ and GND
- It seems you have a scope. You should inspect DOUT while triggering on the falling edge of !CS. You should then be able to see the 24bit answer consisting of a `0` followed by the value, MSB (11) first. After bit 0, it starts to output bits 1...11 again. So, the bit stream is symmetrical, and the bits in the center should flip due to noise, while the outer should not.
- The datasheet says a minimum cycle takes 16 clock cycles, while the output has a length of 24 bits. Though the datasheet does not mention it, it seems you can stop the output and initiate a new conversion after bit 0 has been put on the output. Do you do that, and can you suspend it for debugging?
- Is !CS high for a sufficient period of time? I found no minimum, but may be, there is one.
- The frequency of 3.125MHz is about the maximum the ADC can handle. Can you reduce it (down to 10kHz) to check if it causes problems? Also check if the waveform is in a good shape at the input of your micro controller / FPGA.

Finally, you should first check if the ADC gives reasonable results, which is easy to test with a scope. If everything is fine, you should think about the code of the micro controller / FPGA. As the ADC is quite simple, I doubt that it gives an output of 0 the first time. It's more likey you have a firmware bug.

Comment: I have a 0.1u between Vcc GND and Vref GND, none for +In. The VHDL testbench works fine, as like the datasheet, so I believe there are no SPI control issues

Comment: Well, believing and knowing are distinct things. I also had to learn never to thrust in what I just believe.