# ADC output level query

Tags: adc, analog, sampling

This query is related to my old post: [ADC outputs random values to constant input](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/166405/adc-outputs-random-values-to-constant-input)

I made further tests, and still struggling. The reason I made a new post is, the query is different. I am using  FPGA (Spartan6) to sample the signal. The PMODS can handel a maximum of 3v3. I expected the output of ADC to be below as the input. Also with multimeter I get the same voltage level. But I found in the datasheet (http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads7822.pdf) Page 4 - DIGITAL INPUT / OUTPUT - Logic öevels: Voh = 3V5 (min). That means its from3V5 to 5V. Is my understanding clear?

Comment: Did your previous question get resolved?

Comment: No. Its still open for an answer. I am working out to find the reason and came up with this query.

Answer (score 1):

If the device is powered from 5V, the digital input levels that will work with the device are between 3.5v and 5V - that is what is said on the table on page 4.

On page 3 it quotes the digital input levels for a 2V7 supply and these are between 2V and 5V.

Please note that the digital output levels will be no higher than the power supply you feed it. If you run from a 3V3 supply then you won't get a logic output higher than 3V3 and probably more like 3V.

Comment: The ADC is powered by 5V and a 3V reference. So as per the datasheet I expect  an output between 3V5 and 5V but I always get an output equivalent to the input voltage. This is what I don't understand. If I give a 2V i put I get 2V and I tried all ranges from 0-3V.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying you get a digital serial stream output level that is peaking at the analogue input voltage? How are you measuring this?

Comment: Measuring with a multimeter. I tried varying the input level with a pot and surprisingly the output varies with the input. It is certainly not expected.

Comment: It's a digital serial output and measuring the digital serial stream with a multimeter is not going to tell you anything about the peak output voltage level of the digital stream. If the analogue input is zero volts then the digital stream is going to be all zeros and this will look like 0V on a multimeter. If the analogue input is greater than the ref voltage the serial stream outputted is going to be all 1s and this will look like Vcc. Between these values it may look similar to the input but that is a coincidence based on the number of 1s and 0s in the stream. Use a scope.

Comment: Ok. I understand. Thanks for the detailed explanation. Assuming the output ranges from 3V5 to 5V as per the datasheet, I have one more problem my FPGA can read a maximum of 3V3. Now I have the idea of using a N-MOSFET with a 3V3 input to the drain to limit the maximum voltage. I will get an inverted output. But does this help? Can you give me an idea how do I limit the range to 0-3.3V?

Comment: Use a resistor potential divider to reduce 5V to 3.3V. A 180 ohm and a 330 ohm resistor will turn 5V to 3.24 volts. That will work - no need to use a FET.

Comment: Thank you very much for the very quick solution, let me try this out now. I will update this post once I am done!

Comment: I still have one question. With a voltage divider the 5V is reduces to 3.2V but the 3.5V is still 2.2V which is quite high a poential level to signify logic 0.

Comment: The 3.5V is not logic 0 but the low-end tolerance for logic 1.  logic 1 can be between 3.5V and 5.0V

Comment: Ok I got it. I have a divider with 120 ohm and 220 ohm, its the best i could find in my stock. But I still read wrong values from the ADC. With a contastDC input of 2.2V I get a varying MSB in the output byte.

Comment: What ref voltage are you using? Also remember that this question is about understanding the logic high level as stated in the data sheet. If the ADC isn't working that's another issue.

Comment: I am using a Vref of 3V. The test input I am varing between 0V and 3V

Comment: I tried a voltage divider of 120 ohm and 220 ohm, but still the output to oscilloscope is not satisfactory. I believe it is due to the low current output from the ADC (in uA). With a total of 330 ohm the current is 15 mA at 5V. Is it better to use 12kohm and 22kohm?

Comment: "not satisfactory"?

Comment: I mean the output is still corrupted and in the oscilloscope the output is limted to 0.8V.